# How to manually center button's caption in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have problem with button's caption in VB6.
I'm trying to change caption after "_load" event and it works, but new text is not in the center of the button - and it's a problem.

You can see it on the following screen:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3779161/buttons.png

I've tried to use "Refresh" function but without any effect.
Is it possible to refresh button without creating new one?

Thanks for help

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. It centers automatically for me.

Comment: what button is that? is it some custom usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test VB6 code currently but, apparently, it requires Win-API calls to align the text. [code here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=330). Copy the code into a Module and then you can call the function `AlignCommandButtonText`. (Seems like hard work!)

Answer (score 0):

the new text does center for me.

run the following test project and click on the form:

```
'1 form with
'  1 commandbutton: name=Command1  caption="Test"
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Click()
  Command1.Caption = "New Test"
End Sub
```

the problem is probably caused by something else.
for example: do you have any tight loops?

could you post some of your code?